# Raspberry Pi4, Resolution does not fit screen

Tags: raspberry-pi4

Hello I have problem with my screen on my RP4.

Resolution is only showing left top corner while the rest of interface is not shown.
I tried to change overscan, didn't help.
Tried to play with screen driver settings, didn't help.
Tried also to change resolution to lower, still the same issue.

I would love to post image also but I can't unfortunetly.

For further help, thank you!

Overscan settings, didnt work
Display driver settings, didnt work
Change resolution, didnt work.